# Office 365 navigation bar is sometimes black and sometimes blue within Sharepoint site

Tags: office-365, navigation

Sharepoint site appears sometimes with a blue Office 365 navigation bar at the top and sometimes black. This is the case for our entire organization and not just my Office 365 account. Can I change it so that it stays black in all lists, libraries, and pages?
Is there a reason for this? Is there an update underway? 
It is a team site, classic template, using modern experience on the site I am referring to. It seems it may be related to the whether it's a list/library or modern page. Lists/libraries turn to blue Office 365 navigation bar and pages remain with black navigation bar.
[image: February 11 2019]
new situation
[image: February 7 2019]
original situation

Comment: Hello, can you add screenshots? It is always in same Experiences? New Experiences or the Old Look?

Comment: This is the new experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set default Theme for Tenant:

1. **Log** with Tenant Admin here https://portal.office.com/AdminPortal/Home#/companyprofile
2. Select **Manage custom themes for your organization** (you can add Company Logo too)
3. **Save** your theme

In few moments Theme will be applied for all Looks including New and Old Looks.

[Microsoft Documentation here.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/setup/customize-your-organization-theme?view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: The settings already had nav bar at black. But we reset it anyway. We also changed the "accent" color to black. Not sure which worked, but it looks how I want it to now. Thank you for link to instructions

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Thank you again for your help. However it is happening again in a different way. Any ideas? I attached new screenshots.  Thanks

Comment: Hello, yes its a new feature of look in SPO which they are rolling out. We have the new choices too, I will look at this tomorrow with colleague about the correct settings

Comment: Try to look at the Theme URL if something changed here too.

Comment: Thanks. Theme URL in admin? I still haven’t seen the new “change the look options” in the hub site though I’m on targeted release

Comment: Yes the url from my answer.... It looks that you need to set on each Site the new look with the Accent. So just adjust sites as you want them.